# Why separate the one time password of 2FA as another step?

Tags: authentication, login-control

Many websites now support 2FA and many of them ask users to use an App for the OTP. From the tool I use, like 1password, it seems the OTP is updating all the time regardless to I have logged in the website or not. My question is, since the OTP is always there, why it is split into a standalone step to enter the code instead of asking users to enter it along with the username and password?